# Grab data from other website

Tags: java, jsp, web

I am making a web based application in jsp in which I need to fetch data from other websites. I do not have any idea how to it. I searched in scrapperwiki but nothing was related to jsp.

So how can I grab data from other websites using jsp?

Comment: You mention "from other websites". Do you know how these websites offer their data? In what method, formats? For example, do they offer open API to allow you get data? Do they have web service, like SOAP, REST? Are the data in XML or JSON format? Or they don't offer any of these, you just need a web crawler?

Comment: Grab data means what you need to grab? There are many ways like consuming web services etc. Can you clarify what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Observe the source of the web pages and parse them. there is a 
[project](http://jsoup.org/) that makes it easy.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use a URLConnection:

```
<%@ page language="Java" import="java.net.*,java.io.*"%>  
<%  
        try {  
                URL url = new URL("http://other-website/url/test.txt");  
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();  

                conn.setDoInput(true);  
                conn.setDoOutput(false);  
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));  
                String line=null;  
                line = br.readLine();  
                while ( line != null ) {  
                        %>  
                        <%=line%>  
                        <BR>  
                        <%  
                        line = br.readLine();     
                }  
                br.close();  
        } catch(Exception e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
%>
```

Off course, it's a good idea to put this code in a java controller servlet instead of using it as a scriptlet in your JSP, or even better to use any MVC framework instead of pure Servlet + JSP's.

Comment: JSP's don't go there, either :-)
 The OP was not to evaluate his design or technology choices, but to have a simple solution to a simple problem.

Comment: why not jsps ? I disagree, and would not recommend using scriptlets in any situation.